# selenium no suitable method found for until(ExpectedCondition<WebElement>)

Tags: java, selenium, netbeans

This is a wired issue ! The project I've imported was working 100% (several months ago)
and today I've imported it with the dependencies and there is an issue in
`WebDriverWait`

Here is my code :

```
WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("saveBut1")));//here's the issue
```

Here is the error:

```
no suitable method found for until(ExpectedCondition<WebElement>)
    method FluentWait.until(Predicate<WebDriver>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ExpectedCondition<WebElement> cannot be converted to Predicate<WebDriver>)
    method FluentWait.<V>until(Function<? super WebDriver,V>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) V
        (argument mismatch; ExpectedCondition<WebElement> cannot be converted to Function<? super WebDriver,V>))
  where V,T are type-variables:
    V extends Object declared in method <V>until(Function<? super T,V>)
    T extends Object declared in class FluentWait
```

I'm using Netbeans as IDE and I export the project (3 months ago) using it

Comment: is it a maven project? If so, does it have a dependency without a version number, meaning it could be using a more recent version now?

Comment: i'm using the project with it exact dependency version as it was

Comment: Can you list the dependencies from your pom, it might not be a dependency you declare, but a dependency from a dependency.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue as well, and the problem was (as suggested in the comments above) I lacked the google guava library, which is needed by ExpectedCondition. Once I added that to the project it compiled as expected.